# rust: How to simplify enum nested match?

Tags: enums, rust, nested, match

I got the result for `std::result::Result<Row, sqlx::Error>`, I want to check the row is found.
the right code:

```
let sql = "select id,name from tablename LIMIT 0";
let r = sqlx::query_as::<_, Person>(sql).fetch_one(&pool).await;
if let Err(err) = r {
    match err {
        sqlx::Error::RowNotFound => println!("Not Found!!!"),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

right way 1:

```
if let Err(err) = r {
    if let sqlx::Error::RowNotFound = err {
        println!("Not Found!!!");
    }
}
```

right way 2:

```
r.map_err(|err| if let sqlx::Error::RowNotFound = err {
    println!("Not Found!!!");
});
```

has the more simplify way?

Comment: Just an alternative: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e9dd124db9f76f1672edc945eaf4cab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also match like this:

```rust
match r {
    Err(sqlx::Error::RowNotFound) => println!("Not Found!!!"),
    _ => (),
}
```

You could also look at [match guards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html#match-guards)